# Can I configure TeamCity's built in TomCat server to serve static html files?

Tags: tomcat, teamcity

I want to include the results of the last FxCop and coverage run in our confluence page.  I have got team city to output the report as html to a location of my choosing but I can't include the html file in confluence using the file:// protocol, only via http.

Can I configure the TeamCity built in Tomcat server to serve up (without authorisation) the html file that I have exported?  Then when the build replaces the html file with a new version, the confluence page will automatically be updated?

Comment: Why not add it as a build artifact?

Comment: @AlG it is a build artifact already, but in order for confluence to consume it as a html-include in a page it it needs to accessible via http:// (I tried file:// but no dice) so I need to get it served, and the simplest way would seem to be getting the already running tomcat that serves up the TeamCity pages to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think I figured this out.  It seems that its configured to handle only .html requests, and so by renaming the file to be `fxcop-report.htm` and placing it in the TeamCity\webapps\ROOT directory directly I can use a standard `http:\\teamcityurl\fxcop-report.htm` call to get the file served up.

It seems I have to do some tweaking of the contents of the html produced by FxCop as what gets embedded by confluence seems only to be the body of the FxCop page, so I get no javascript functions, but I can work on that I think.

Comment: dropping a line nearly 6 years later to say thanks for this! By the way, do you know why it is that .htm works but a file called .html will 404?